# Remote Laravel and PhpStorm: howto?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am working on a Laravel installation, and I am using used Visual Studio Code: I mount the installation directory as a remote disk (I am on a Mac) and I work directly on the server itself.

If I want to use PhpStorm (that does not allow me to work on remote files), what do I have to do? How can I deal with `php artisan make:<whatever>` commands? I mean: these commands modify source files, and if I run them on the server I'd have to merge the modified remote files on my local work files.

Should I run `artisan` directly on my Mac instead? Is it safe, after this, to simply deploy the local files to remote server, or there's some sync procedure to follow?

Comment: You should develop locally and deploy your application on your server.

Comment: ... and run artisan commands locally? will it work the same way? there's nothing machine-dependent?

Comment: and in phpstorm check the `settings->build, execution and deployment->deployment` section. Also check the phpstorm documentation for more. Start with: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html

Comment: Run the commands in the environment where you need it. Run it on your local machine if you need to run that command locally - run the command on server if you need to run the command on server.

Comment: You might want to look into GIT: https://git-scm.com/

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: maybe :-) I am trying to develop locally and then deploy via remote server connection. I am just wondering if everything will work fine (i.e. if artisan commands will rely on libraries that I have on my local system and I won't have on my shared hosting environment)

Answer (score 0):

Possible.

The page opens if you have selected the Add `new remote server` option on the Create New Project: Specify Remote Server page. On this page, specify a new configuration of settings to connect and authenticate to a remote server.

Read more: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html